# Writing a spark script to read a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create my first spark script which reads a file and show the content via spark dataframe. I have created a file df.scala and written the below code inside it.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/home/ec2-user/myspark/files/emp.txt")
df.show()
```

But when I trying to execute this file, Its giving me error as below. Need your suggestions on how to fix it.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-131 df]$ /home/ec2-user/spark/bin/spark-submit df.scala
20/12/11 19:58:46 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
20/12/11 19:58:46 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'null'.  Please specify one with --class.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
  [ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-131 df]$
```

Is it due to class not defined inside the script but then is there any way to run spark job without a script ?

Comment: you can try to run your code in spark-shell. if you use spark-submit, I guess you need to have a main class in your script

Comment: @mck Thanks. I tried running the file with spark-shell but now getting below error :df.scala:26: error: not found: value df
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/home/ec2-user/myspark/files/emp.txt")

Comment: you need to define df: `val df = ...`

Comment: @mck : Thanks a ton mate. All issues are now resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

`spark-submit` takes a JAR file along with a `--class` argument for the class to run, and so not a script.

If you just want to run a script, then you would use `spark-shell`

Answer (score 0):

Type in command line: `spark-shell`, and try the code.

After it's correct, you can wrap it in a `sbt` project, here's a [mini example](https://github.com/Jackgmlin/mini-spark-with-sbt.git) showing you how to create and run a sbt project.